# Comparar 2 tablas iguales en Servidores diferentes - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

¿Existe algún medio para comparar 2 tablas en Bases de Datos diferentes y diferentes Servidores?

Estoy buscando una respuesta a esa pregunta, por que se me dio este ejercicio.

Lo primero que había pensado es obtener ambas tablas directamente con un select a cada una, y eso son 2 conexiones diferentes. Pero entonces, ¿Como comparo las tablas luego?

Lo que necesito comparar y obtener, es si en la tablaA faltan ids de la tablaB. `claveboleta` es el campo a comparar.

```
<?php
//ServidorA
$usuario = "";
$password = "";
$servidor = "";
$basededatos = "";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
$db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos) or die("Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

//ServidorB
$uServidor = "";
$pServidor = "";
$dServidor = "";
$bdServidor = "";
$cServidor = mysqli_connect($dServidor, $uServidor, $pServidor) or die("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos remoto");
$dbServ = mysqli_select_db($cServidor, $bdServidor) or die("Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos remoto");

$selectLocal = "SELECT claveboleta FROM boletas";
$selectBowa = "SELECT claveboleta FROM boletas";
```

Ya luego de obtenerlas entonces, como puedo comparar ambas tablas ???

Comment: Supongo que lo más práctico seria recoger ambos datos con matrices y luego usar array_diff para compararlas.

Comment: Como es eso de matrices ??

Comment: Creo que vosotros lo llamais arreglos. En ingles array

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa. ¿Qué quieres decir cuando hablas de *servidores diferentes*? ¿Te refieres a dos bases de datos en dos servidores distintos o a dos bases de datos en el mismo servidor? ¿A qué te refieres con *comparar*? ¿Qué hay que comparar en concreto, qué resultados se esperan? *Comparar* puede significar miles de cosas, por ejemplo: que un dato existe en A y no en B, o que un dato es mayor en A que en B, o que un dato es menor en A que en B, etc, etc, etc. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y aclara el problema, si es posible poniendo un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener.

Comment: @A.Cedano Servidores diferentes es eso, servidores diferentes, no veo la confusión en eso. La comparación igual es tácita en la publicación `si en la tablaA faltan ids de la tablaB`.

Comment: [El término *servidor* es ambiguo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)). Puede referirse al **hardware** (la computadora que aloja sitios webs, bases de datos, archivos, etc) o al **software** (un sistema operativo, un SGBD -SQLServer, Postgresql, MySQL, etc-, una API. un servicio web, etc). Si lo que quieres es comparar dos tablas (es lo que parece por el código) basta con una consulta del tipo `LEFT JOIN` que una ambas tablas. En los no coincidentes tendrás `NULL`, lo que será suficiente para saber qué registros de una tabla no existen en la otra.

Comment: Si estamos hablando **de dos bases de datos en servidores distintos (en distintas máquinas)** puedes hacer uso de *linked server*  para unir ambas tablas. Si hablamos de  **dos bases de datos en el mismo servidor (misma máquina)**, puedes unir las tablas en la consulta poniendo delante de los nombres de tabla el nombre de su respectiva base de datos (a condición de que el usuario con el que conectas tenga los permisos necesarios en ambas BD). Otra opción, más costosa, sería consultar ambas BD por separado y luego comparar los datos de algún modo.

Comment: @A.Cedano: Ya habia mirado antes de contestar si existia algo parecido en MySQL, y encontré lo del [FEDERATED Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) pero me pareció demasiado complejo para su pregunta. Ahora veo que hablas de _linked server_ que parece más bien orientado a SQL server de M$. En cuanto a eso, el OP al incluir en su pregunta funciones `mysqli` entiendo que usa MySQL 4.1 en adelante y no SQL server. Y de ahí deduzco que son servidores de MySQL distintos (ya sea por máquinas distintas, o VPS, o dockers o cualquier variedad posible).

Comment: Pero si puse que eran MYSQL, me estoy perdiendo.

Comment: Olvidate de esta discusion, creo que A. Cedano se confundio un poco, (o no, pero ya lo dira cuando esté) y centrate en tu problema... ¿has mirado lo que te he comentado con el array_diff antes?  De momento es la solucion más sencilla (a pesar que quizas no sea la mas optima, claro, pero seguramente te funcionara)

Comment: Correcto, hasta ahora es la funcion que he estado usando, y está funcionando. Aunque me da algunos falsos positivos, pero ya averiguaré porque.

Comment: mmm... ¿falsos positivos?  ¿No será por tener valores duplicados?  Haz los `SELECT` con `DISTINCT` o bien usa `array_unique` y `sort` sobre los arrays antes de compararlos con `array_diff`. A ver si va ser eso.

Comment: Primero averiguaré porque pasa eso